# iOS and Swift: Sharing code between View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I know I will need a good amount of code to be shared throughout my app's different view controllers and I'm not sure the best way of organizing my code. For instance, I know that both view controllers will rely heavily on a particular structure, but I don't know where to declare this structure. My first guess would be to create some kind of file that would be imported by both ViewControllers, but I don't know whether this is the right way to go or not.

I'm still a little new to Swift and iOS programming and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you heard of inheritance, super classes, polymorphism? if you are talking about that topic by saying "rely heavily on a particular structure"!?

Comment: I know a little bit about those things, yes. What I mean by the structure comment is that I have a 'post' struct that will be used heavily in each of the view controllers. In one, posts will be viewed in a list, in the other, they will be viewed on a map. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Okay, then you basically just need to define a class called `Post` fitting your needs and you are ready to go.

Comment: Which of the View Controllers should that definition be in, if any?

Comment: None, keep the post definition seperate, in a different / new file.

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I was looking for. So stick it in a new file and use import statements in the View Controllers?

Comment: You need to get familiar with Model-View-Controller. Data and data structures etc. are generally stored and handled and made available via a Model class. Therefore the Model class will own and make available the post struct and both the view controllers access it. "So stick it in a new file and use import statements in the View Controllers" All that will do is share the *definition* of the post struct, you need to share an actual *instantiated object* of the post struct if you want the controllers to access the values held in the struct. This is done via a Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be referring to some common business logic both of your controllers need to access. This can be done by having business logic classes that you either instantiate by each controller or using a singleton helper class (just don't store state in the singleton!).

Check out the [MVC programming design pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC_Design_Pattern)

The controllers can then pass information between each other in the form of context (an object) or an identifier to an object (e.g. an ID in a database table) and have the receiving controller call the related business objects to retrieve the necessary information.